# Python function returning string which is function name, need to execute the returned statement

Tags: python, string

1) Function 1 encodes the string

def Encode(String):
   ..
   ..code block
   ..
   return String

2) Function 2 return the string, which actually forms function call of Function 1

def FunctionReturningEncodeFuntionCall(String):
   ..
   ..code block
   ..
   return EncodeFunctionString

3) In Function 3 parse the string and pass to Function 2 to form Function 1 call and execute the Function 1 and store its returned value

def LastFuntionToAssignValue(String):
   ..
   ..code block
   ..
   a = exec FunctionReturningMyFuntionCall("abcd") 
   print a

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try `a = globals()[FunctionReturningMyFunctionCall("abcd")](...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 i tried your suggestion but its giving me Keyerror, just to clarify as per my example 'Encode' is imported

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [exec statement](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest way is to use a dictionary where the key is the function's name and the value is the function itself.